# rundeck make job with multiple steps on different nodes

Tags: rundeck

How can a Job with multiple steps run some steps on **Node 1** and other on **Node 2**?
For example:

On **Node 1**, I have to copy a file to a folder `cp file.txt /var/www/htm/`

On **Node 2**, I have to download this file `wget https://www.mywebsite.com/file.txt`

I have tried creating three jobs,

**JOB 1**, workflow I have **Execute Command on remote** `cp file.txt /var/www/htm/` and NODES filter to my **NODE 1**

**JOB 2**, workflow I have **Execute Command on remote** `wget https://www.mywebsite.com/file.txt` and NODES filter to **NODE 2**

**JOB 3**, workflow step 1: selected Job Reference, and paste the UUID from JOB 1, step 2 Job reference and paste UUID **JOB 2** and node filter I writed `.*` to get all nodes.

For now I tried to only run a command `ls`(on JOB 1 and JOB 2), but when I run **JOB 3** the output is 3 time the command each job, for example:

```
// Run Job 3
// Output from Job 1
test-folder
test.text
test-folder
test.text
test-folder
test.text
```

And same for **JOB 2**

How can I implement my job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step) is the right way to solve that, but instead of defining `.*` to get all nodes, you can use the node1 name in the first job reference step call and the node2 name for the second job reference call, on "Override node filters?" section. Alternatively you can define the nodes filter in each job and just call it from the Job 3 using job reference step.

Comment: I used job reference step and selected "No" on "Override" section, but when execute this job, show "Warning: no nodes filters". So I changed setting to "Yes" and on "node filter" (Override section  on Job Reference Step), I filtered again the same node filtered on job reference, and this works ¿It's ok?